# Keyfile Access Control in a Replica Set and Internal Authentication

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-internal-auth

I'm using MongoDB 3.2.6 and I want to use Keyfile Access Control for MongoDB replication.

What I read in this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/

> Enforcing access control on a replica set requires configuring Security between members of the replica set using Internal
>   Authentication

Unfortunately I can not find in the link below how I enable Internal Authentication:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/

Should I configure `auth = true` in the mongo configuration file (and configure users)?

How I enable Internal Authentication?

The opposite question:
If I will enable configure `auth = true` in the mongo configuration then I have to use Keyfile Access Control for the MongoDB replication (otherwise the MongoDB replication will not work).

Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a separate option to enable internal authentication. Basically, internal authentication and client authentication need to be either both enabled or both disabled.

Note, that specifying the `keyFile` will implicitly enable authentication (e.g. setting `auth=true` is redundant/implied and not required). But setting both keyFile and auth is probably a good idea to avoid confusion.

When authentication is enabled and you are running a replica set or sharded cluster, then you **must** utilize one of the internal authentication mechanisms to allow the members to authenticate and communicate with each other. Meaning you will need to either use a keyFile or x.509 authentication in order for replication/sharding to work.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question I asked: If I configure `auth=true` can I use the MongoDB replication without `security.keyFile` (
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile)?

Comment: I revised my answer, hopefully that clarifies. If authentication is enabled you have to use either keyFile or x.509 otherwise replication and/or sharding will not work.

Comment: @helmy I am attempting to apply internal authentication on my replica set. Do you know if I need to create my admin/root user prior or after enabling the internal authentication in the conf and restarting? And will that admin user have control of the entire replica set?

Comment: @Richard you can create your admin user either before or after enabling auth. If you do it after you rely on connecting via the "localhost exception" to create the first user. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception